# How to add a new property to constructor function using the this keyword?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add a new property to my constructor function having the 'this' keyword, but I don't know exactly how.

```
function Dog(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age; 
}
```

And I'd like something like this:

```
Dog['this.type'] = type;

console.log(Dog);

function Dog(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age; 
    this.type = type;
}
```

Any ideas? Or it doesn't work like this?

Comment: It doesn't work like that.

Comment: You can't modify an existing function. You can however add properties to the constructor's prototype object, and you can do that at any time.

Comment: I can't actually work out what you're trying to do

Comment: I'd recommend going through: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: I don't understand this, either. There's no `type` parameter to the new constructor function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm new in Javascript, but I've got it now.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add a property to a constructor function at runtime, you can do it by adding to the constructor prototype

for example

```
function Dog(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

const dog = new Dog('dog', 2);

Dog.prototype.greet = function(){
    console.log(`hello from ${this.name}, that is ${this.age} years old`);
} 

dog.greet() // prints hello from dog, that is 2 years old
```